# Dataset: Failure when using functions that generate messages

Tags: dataset

Consider the dataset:

```
data = Dataset[{<|"A" -> 1|>, <| "A" -> 2|>}]
```

Define the function:

```
f[x_] := (Message[f::test]; x);
```

Note that `f[1]` returns `1` and `f[2]` returns `2`, although messages are printed.

The following returns a `Failure`:

```
data[All, f[#["A"]] &]

(* Failure[f, Association["MessageTemplate" :> MessageName[f, "test"], 
   "MessageParameters" -> {}]]  *)
```

I have code that breaks because of this (messages from `FindRoot` were the culprit).

**Update**: As suggested by @Edmund in the comments, `data[All, Quiet[f[#["A"]]]&]` works. But `Quiet[data[All, f[#["A"]] &]]` does not.

Comment: The above code does not work in 10.3.1, 10.4.1, and 11.0 in Win 8.1 Pro.  What version of *Mathematica* did it used to work in.

Comment: Not sure. I thought it was working fine before. But the data did changed. So messages may not have been generated before

Comment: @Edmund Changed the question accordingly

Comment: Have you seen [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html)?

Comment: Yes. But that seems like a nasty solution

Comment: interesting, `Quiet` only works when inside the function, that is, `data[All, (f#["A"]//Quiet)&]` but does not work when outside, `data[All, f[#["A"]]&]//Quiet`.

Comment: `data[All, Quiet@f[#["A"]] &]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behaviour we see is due to the default [FailureAction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FailureAction.html) associated with dataset queries.  The default action is to abort the entire computation if any message is issued:

```
data[All, If[#A == 1, #, Message[f::test]] &]

(* Failure[...] *)
```

Fortunately, we can override this behaviour.  For example, we can instruct the query to take no special action in the face of messages:

```
data[All, If[#A == 1, #, f[#]] &, FailureAction -> None]

(*
   f: -- Message text not found --
   { <| "A" -> 1|>, <| "B" -> 1 |> }
 *)
```

Messages are issued as normal and the final dataset is produced.  Incidentally, this option is *incredibly* useful when debugging complex dataset queries.

We can also drop each individual result if its computation issues a message:

```
data[All, If[#A == 1, #, f[#]] &, FailureAction -> "Drop"]

(* { <| "A" -> 1 |> } *)
```

... or encapsulate individual failed results within `Failure` objects:

```
data[All, If[#A == 1, #, f[#]] &, FailureAction -> "Encapsulate"]

(* <| "A" -> 1 |>, Failure[...] } *)
```

... or replace failed results with a `Missing` expression:

```
data[All, If[#A == 1, #, f[#]] &, FailureAction -> "Replace"]

(* {<|"A" -> 1|>, Missing["Failed"]} *)
```

We can enhance most of the action types with a user function which is applied to `Failure` objects (the function `g` in this example):

```
data[All, If[#A == 1, #, f[#]] &, FailureAction -> {"Replace", g}]

(* { <| "A" -> 1 |>, g[Failure[...]] } *)
```

Finally, we can explicitly specify the "Abort" action which is the default:

```
data[All, If[#A == 1, #, f[#]] &, FailureAction -> "Abort"]

(* Failure[...] *)
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. Is this behavior documented?

Comment: I can see that it is (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FailureAction.html). Thanks!